# Precalculus AM-GM(?) Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be real numbers such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$ Find the maximum value of $9x+12y+8z.$

I'm not sure exactly how to proceed. I tried to AM-GM $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1,$ but I couldn't relate it back to $9x+12y+8z.$

Answers? Comments? Advice?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Answer (score 5):

One way to approach this problem is to note that the function that’s being maximized is the dot product of $(x,y,z)$ with $(9,12,8)$. For a fixed-length $(x,y,z)$, this will be at a maximum when the vectors are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

if $A=(x,y,z), B=(9,12,8)$, then their inner product is $AB=9x+12y+8z$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you can get $|AB|\leq (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}(81+144+64)^{\frac{1}{2}}$